# Are there any eigenvalue decomposition methods in C++ faster than MATLAB's eig function?

Tags: matlab, eigen, blas, intel-mkl, eigen3

Why does the `eig()` in MATLAB run so fast? How does it make? I use the Eigen's EigenSolver, it is very slower than MATLAB. Using `Intel-MKL`? Can we achieve equal or higher performance than MATLAB? or `BLAS`/`LAPACK`/`ATLAS`/`ARPACK`/`OpenBLAS`/`GotoBLAS`/`ACML`? What is the industrial solutions of eigenvalue decomposition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matlab uses MKL as its BLAS and LAPACK backend. And MKL is the fastest (in almost all the cases) library for BLAS and LAPACK on Intel CPUs.

You could use these command to check the version of MKL used by Matlab

```
>> version -blas
>> version -lapack
```

See this link for some benchmark results done by Intel himself.

http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl#pid-12780-836

Comment: Thanks, Eric. In my computer, the command says that `MATLAB` use `MKL 10.3.11`. I have downloaded the `MKL` non-commercial version. I am a newbie to it, and I have not used it because of some link errors. I think `Intel-MKL` for `MATLAB` is processed by some industrial optimization.

Comment: Except for version update, the only difference between non-commercial version and the commercial version as the one in matlab is the license agreement. The performance are same.

Comment: OK, I know. Thanks, Eric.